# Flask-SocketIO: Cannot connect to a namespace

Tags: socket.io, flask-socketio

I have problems connecting to my server via Websockets while using Flask-SocketIO. Everything works if I don't specify a custom namespace, but if I want to connect to a namespace I cannot connect. What am I doing wrong?

I made a small scratch program, which shows my problem:

```py
### removed to make the post less long, see below ###
```

I'm pretty sure I connect the client wrong. But I don't know how to do it right. I looked through the SocketIO Client documentation, but couldn't find help.

#### EDIT:

---

To make it clearer, here is an updated version with just one socket:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on("connect", namespace="/test")
def handle_connect():
   print("heureka!")
   return True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask-SocketIO Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var socket1 = io("http://127.0.0.1:5000/test");
        socket1.on("connect", function() {
            console.log("yay!")
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Testing
</body>
</html>
"""

socketio.run(app, debug=True, log_output=True, use_reloader=False)
```

I can see the requests the socket is sending in my terminal:

```
(6548) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(6548) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 59354)
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2020 19:15:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 691 0.000000
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2020 19:15:58] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NQqtHrO HTTP/1.1" 200 371 0.000997
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2020 19:15:59] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NQqtI28 HTTP/1.1" 200 371 0.000997
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2020 19:16:00] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NQqtILH HTTP/1.1" 200 371 0.000000
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2020 19:16:03] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NQqtJ0u HTTP/1.1" 200 371 0.000996
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2020 19:16:08] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NQqtKFD HTTP/1.1" 200 371 0.001002
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2020 19:16:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NQqtLTa HTTP/1.1" 200 371 0.001024
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path` option that you are using is not to specify the namespace, it is used to indicate a custom Socket.IO endpoint. Normally you do not need to set the path.

The namespace is given in the connection URL:

```
var socket1 = io("/test");
```

Or if you prefer an absolute URL:

```
var socket1 = io("http://localhost:5000/test");
```

Comment: That is what I thought, but I tried that too. You see in the example `socket2` is initialized like that, but it also does not work. I did try every option in the mockup script on it's own too, btw. Did not make a difference.

Comment: What's interesting, is that I see the requests the socket is sending on the terminal, but the `handle_connect` function is never called.

Comment: But you changed the code, you are not using what I gave you. Instead of connecting to the relative namespace (`/test`) or to the full hostname plus namespace (`http://localhost:5000/test`) you decided to connect to the IP address (`http://127.0.0.1/test`), which is different and brings cross-origin issues. Do it how I told you and it should work!

Comment: Sorry, I should have put your example in the question. But again, I tried it all. The cross-origin issues only happen when I go to the different URL (meaning if try to connect the socket to `http://localhost:5000/test` I have to visit `http://localhost:5000`. But it also works if I use to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` and `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test`. Otherways I get the cross-origin error). I also tried the relative `/test`, where both `localhost:5000` and `127.0.0.1:5000` should work. Both do not work. There has to be a different mistake.

Comment: I just set up a new environment and tested it there. It works. I don't know what is breaking it on my project environment, but it has nothing to do with the code. I try to do a fresh install of all packages there. Thanks for your effort, it's really remarkable how you try to answer every question and issue on your package. Thanks.